# Angular: properly bind a model to a select to show default value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

In angular I have a select element with its model:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="items" id="items" ng-model="myModel">
          <option value ="10">10</option>
          <option value ="20">20</option>
          <option value ="30">30</option>
 </select>
 {{myModel}}
```

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.myModel = "20";
```

When the page is loaded, `{{myModel}}` is equal to `20`, but the select box is empty, instead of displaying `20`. Later, if I change the value of that box also `{{myModel}}` value changes. It seems properly bound. But how can I display correct value on page load (and why does it happen?)

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7cwPQbH3ebdRAy4Zb5vY?p=preview) to see the problem in action

Comment: I tried to create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uqgBuOqrS87fCsiSJ3mv?p=preview) to recreate your issue, and the code you posted here works correctly.

Comment: Yes, it's true...I don't know where I am wrong : /

Comment: as it stands, your code does not reproduce the behavior you are suggesting your are seeing.  More code would be necessary in order to identify what is different in your project.

Comment: If I had to *make a guess* at the problem, I would think it might have something to do with `myModel` being a primitive instead of an object, which has scope inheritance issues, especially if this code were inside an `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I cannot post all the code here because it too huge. I am trying to extrapolate the main traits but I have not an `ng-repeat`.

Comment: other things than `ng-repeat` can cause scope issues with primitives, `ng-if` and `ng-include` are two other commonly used directives that create child scopes.  Consider changing your model to an object, i.e. `myModel` to `myModel.optionValue` or something similar and see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: @Claies I reproduced the problem in a plnkr. Please, check out the edited question on top.

Comment: I'm trying to review your case now... I can see that the issue is with angular interpreting your model as a number in one case and as a string in the other case, but I'm unclear as to why or how that is occurring at this moment.

Comment: Aha! your model is definitely being converted to a number by the `st-table` directive.  You have two options; I'm working out an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As demonstrated by a [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/nultYUnIFtItfztvjYh2?p=preview) of your original [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7cwPQbH3ebdRAy4Zb5vY?p=preview), the problem is being caused by the `st-table` directive.

This directive is changing your `itemsPerPage` property into a number.  Due to [limitations of the angular select directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), `ng-model` for select can only be a string.

> Note that the value of a select directive used without `ngOptions` is always a string. When the model needs to be bound to a non-string value, you must either explicitly convert it using a directive (see example below) or use `ngOptions` to specify the set of options. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present.

You have 3 options which can be used to overcome this situation:

1. use `ng-options` to populate the `<options>`.
2. Bind your `ng-model` property to a separate property from the property being passed to `st-table`.
3. Convert the model to a string explicitly, as demonstrated in the last code sample on the [angular select documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select):

```js
.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return parseInt(val, 10);
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return '' + val;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<select convert-to-number class="form-control" name="items" id="items" 
        ng-model="itemsByPage">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>​
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KbVd9vjihS1zrmIBCptF?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

try to do this way using [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

```
<select name="myModel" id="myModel"
      ng-options=" option  for option in select track by option "
      ng-model="myModel">
```

Javascript :

```
$scope.myModel = "30";
$scope.select = [10,20,30];
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmMRZpkNGHaTLRJPYAX3?p=preview)

UPDATE--

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmMRZpkNGHaTLRJPYAX3?p=preview) for given script

Comment: yes,your code working properly for me.Please check updated answer. I have given alternate answer.